# How to retrieve firebase database to recylerview without adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am creating social media app on that I have done with Retrieveing database to recycler view and Onclick listener also but I want to initialize layout inflater to adapter class for bottom sheet.
I am using adapter class for clicking events and playing videos like that. I can't add layout inflater to adapter class.
Because I am just inflating XML using adapter and adapter class
Contains recycler view class only it's not contains Appcompat Activity. So think this a problem and why I am asking to retrieve firebase database to recycler view without adapter.

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class CommentAdapter(private var context: Context, private var data: 
List<Comment>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val row: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.commentpostsnamashivaya, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(row)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.commentTv.text = data[position].getComment()

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return data.size
}

inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var commentTv: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_text)
    var report_post_of_lord: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.report_user_of_lordshivaproduct)
    var sharepost: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_share_somam)
    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, viewing_post_nama::class.java)
            val position: Int = adapterPosition
            intent.putExtra("Comment", data[position].getComment())
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }

      report_post_of_lord.setOnClickListener{
        Toast.makeText(context,"Reporting Post . . . . .", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

 //here is my problem here i just only mentioned layoutinflater only.
      val layinf = 
 LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.thisisforbsheet, parent, 
 false)

      }

        sharepost.setOnClickListener{
            val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            val text = data[position].getComment() + "BY COMMENTING APP FROM LORD SHIVA PRODUCTS FAMILY :) "
            shareIntent.type = "text/plain"
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"SHARE COMMENT"))
        }
    }

}
```

Ps: learning English

**EDIT**:
I Added code of adapter class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way to use a RecyclerView without an adapter.  That would not make sense: the entire point of RecyclerView is that it is backed by an adapter.

Comment: ok, thank you. How can I use the Layout inflater inside of it?. CHECK MY EDITED QUESTION.

Comment: Pass a `LayoutInflater` into the constructor of the adapter. See [this adapter](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/blob/master/RecyclerViewBasics/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/sampler/recyclerview/ColorAdapter.kt) from [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/master/RecyclerViewBasics), profiled in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-rv-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).

Comment: Ok i think it will help me

Comment: @CommonsWare please post your comment as the answer so I can upvote and make that an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `LayoutInflater` is just an object. It is easy to get one, such as by calling `getLayoutInflater()` on your `Activity`. And you can then pass it to the `RecyclerView.Adapter`, such as via a constructor parameter.

For example, here is a `RecyclerView.Adapter` that accepts a `LayoutInflater` as a constructor parameter:

```kotlin
/*
  Copyright (c) 2018-2020 CommonsWare, LLC

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  Covered in detail in the book _Elements of Android Jetpack_

  https://commonsware.com/Jetpack
*/

package com.commonsware.jetpack.sampler.recyclerview

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import com.commonsware.jetpack.sampler.recyclerview.databinding.RowBinding

class ColorAdapter(private val inflater: LayoutInflater) :
  ListAdapter<Int, ColorViewHolder>(ColorDiffer) {

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
  ): ColorViewHolder {
    return ColorViewHolder(RowBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false))
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ColorViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindTo(getItem(position))
  }

  private object ColorDiffer : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Int>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldColor: Int, newColor: Int): Boolean {
      return oldColor == newColor
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldColor: Int, newColor: Int): Boolean {
      return areItemsTheSame(oldColor, newColor)
    }
  }
}
```

The activity can create an instance of it via `ColorAdapter(layoutInflater)`:

```kotlin
/*
  Copyright (c) 2018-2020 CommonsWare, LLC

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  Covered in detail in the book _Elements of Android Jetpack_

  https://commonsware.com/Jetpack
*/

package com.commonsware.jetpack.sampler.recyclerview

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.commonsware.jetpack.sampler.recyclerview.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private val random = Random()

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.items.apply {
      layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
      addItemDecoration(
        DividerItemDecoration(this@MainActivity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
      )
      adapter = ColorAdapter(layoutInflater).apply {
        submitList(buildItems())
      }
    }
  }

  private fun buildItems() = List(25) { random.nextInt() }
}
```

Comment: This is actually works

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is way i think it will resolve your issue. You can use firebase recycler adapter to populate data in recyclerview. Here is a link how we can use this

https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/database/readme/

Comment: ok, thanks but how to do this? check my edited question

Comment: Issue is you want activity context to show bottom sheet when you use it in your activity class you can easily get the scope of that class and show bottom sheet.

Comment: But i am Receiving error like missing arguments viewgroup.what can i do

Comment: Why are you showing on handle click in adapter class that is a bad practice you should communicate adapter with activity and handle all the events that will be more convenient and easy way. Use high order functions or interface for that.